# How to print tables with columns names and columns info by using resultSet.getTables()?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, metadata

I have a problem, because I am trying to write a code whose will take infos from db about tabes and columns and I have problem to take this info from Oracle DB, I take this infos from MySQL,Apache DB,SQLite and Access, but when i am trying to do it from Oracle the program stops at line "ResultSet rs = meta.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});"
So here is my question why this code not working :

```
        try {
        DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = meta.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
        while (rs.next()) {
            String dbName = rs.getString("TABLE_CAT") != null ? rs.getString("TABLE_CAT") : "";
            String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            Collection<Column> columnInfo = getColumnInfos(con, tableName, dbName);
            Table tableInfo = new Table(tableName, dbName, columnInfo);
        }
```

but when I use a special query to take all users tables from Oracle DB it's working fine, below code with using query:

```
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select object_name from user_objects where object_type = 'TABLE'");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String tableName = resultSet.getString(1);
            System.out.println(tableName);
            Collection<Column> columnInfo= getColumnInfos(con,tableName,"orcl");
            Table tableInfo = new Table(tableName,"orcl",columnInfo);
}
```

So what can I change in the first code to fix them?
The picture present my db:
[MyDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htU7x.png)

Comment: "...he program stops at line..." -- what's the error? Oracle is known to be slow when retrieving metadata. Wait at least a minute to see the results.

Comment: without error, just when i'm using debugger program stop at this line, I'm waitning about 15 minutes

Comment: I'd say check your JDK and JDBC driver version, for Oravle 19 you need at least JDK1.8 and `ojdbc8.jar`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I added post below with log results

Comment: Based on Oracle JDBC FAQ [What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) you should for an Oracle 19 use JDK8 to JDK11 with either ojdbc8.jar or ojdbc10.jar. I'm using JDK8 with ojdbc8.jar with no problem for your cesa.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I propably found the problem, the problem is that my program scan all tables but in my case in Oracle SQL Developer in my connection I have antoher users(i don't know why) and program load all tables from others users so it's no working correctly. It's possible to create connection without any others users in db because i want to take all metadate from users tables without using SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

@Marmite Bomber Okey so,I checked infos about connection by added sout's to code and I think thats i got right results:

```
        String databaseProductVersion = metaData.getDatabaseProductVersion();
        System.out.println(databaseProductVersion);
        String userName = metaData.getUserName();
        System.out.println(userName);
        String driverName = metaData.getDriverName();
        System.out.println(driverName);
        String driverVersion = metaData.getDriverVersion();
        System.out.println(driverVersion);
        String url = metaData.getURL();
        System.out.println(url);
```

After run it in the console i have results like:

```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:
    C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50486:
    C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 - 
    classpath 
    C:\Users\target\classes;

    C:\Users\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.23\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc10\19.3.0.0\ojdbc10-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ucp\19.3.0.0\ucp-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\oraclepki\19.3.0.0\oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\osdt_cert\19.3.0.0\osdt_cert-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\osdt_core\19.3.0.0\osdt_core-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\ha\simplefan\19.3.0.0\simplefan-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\ha\ons\19.3.0.0\ons-19.3.0.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\xerial\sqlite-jdbc\3.34.0\sqlite-jdbc-3.34.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derbyclient\10.15.2.0\derbyclient-10.15.2.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derbyshared\10.15.2.0\derbyshared-10.15.2.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\net\sf\ucanaccess\ucanaccess\5.0.1\ucanaccess-5.0.1.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.5.0\hsqldb-2.5.0.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\healthmarketscience\jackcess\jackcess\3.0.1\jackcess-3.0.1.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.8.1\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar Main
    Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
    Version 19.3.0.0.0
    C##SCOTT
    Oracle JDBC driver
    19.3.0.0.0
    jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

and my pom dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

If betters will be added screen I can do it. Like you see in logs I'm using JDK 15 and ojdbc10.

I propably found the problem, the problem is that my program scan all tables but in my case in Oracle SQL Developer in my connection I have antoher users(i don't know why) and program load all tables from others users so it's no working correctly. It's possible to create connection without any others users in db because i want to take all metadate from users tables without using SQL query?

[OthersUsersOracleSQLDeveloper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LwZI.png)